# How does AWS CodeStar SpringBoot Lambda app work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, aws-codestar

Can someone please help me  understand how the Hello World Java SpringBoot sample created by AWS CodeStar  works when its deployed to lambda ?

What I cannot seem to understand is :-

There is a @SpringBootApplication annotation in the Main Application class, but how does this link to the handler/HelloWorldHandler.java ?

There seems to be no annotation in the HelloWorldHandler class which would indicate that it needs to be invoked when called by AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `AWS Lambda` console, find and open the Lambda function you created with `AWS CodeStar`.  Then click the `Configuration` tab and you'll see the `Handler` property has specified the package containing the handler method:

```
com.aws.codestar.projecttemplates.handler.HelloWorldHandler
```

That's how `AWS Lambda` knows what to execute.

Comment: Ok, so I guess the SpringBoot stuff is not used at all. i.e Its just a place holder if you want to use Spring later on (?)

Comment: @Shahed Pretty much.